# Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'. ts(2322)

Tags: typescript

So I am trying to create a dragbar for resizing containers.

```
var handler = document.querySelector('.handler') as HTMLElement;
var wrapper = handler!.closest('.wrapper') as HTMLElement;
var boxA = wrapper!.querySelector('.box') as HTMLElement;
var isHandlerDragging = false;
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  if (e.target === handler) {
    isHandlerDragging = true;
  }
});

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  if (!isHandlerDragging) {
    return false;
  }
  var containerOffsetLeft = wrapper!.offsetLeft;
  var pointerRelativeXpos = e.clientX - containerOffsetLeft;  
  boxA!.style.width = (Math.max(boxAminWidth, pointerRelativeXpos - 8)) + 'px';
  boxA!.style.flexGrow = 0;   //Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

How can I declare **boxA**, so that it is of type number?

I am new to typescript so any suggestions are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to change `boxA`'s type. The error it's saying that the property `flexGrow` of `boxA!.style` is a string, but you're trying to assign a number to it.

So instead try:

```js
boxA!.style.flexGrow = "0";
```

Also, you don't really need to use the [non-null-assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator), the `!` operator. Since you've already asserted that `boxA` is an `HTMLElement`, Typescript knows that it has a `style` property.

So, in the end you can write it like this:

```js
boxA.style.flexGrow = "0";
```

Comment: I am trying to change boxA's type to integer, cause if I do ```boxA.style.flexGrow = "0";``` that removes the error but the code doesn't work as intended. I am trying to replicate the most upvoted answer of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46931103/making-a-dragbar-to-resize-divs-inside-css-grids

Comment: @Tallion22 How exactly does it not work as expected? I tried it here https://jsfiddle.net/2urn3cx0/16/

Comment: For some reason it's not working in my vue application. I'll try to debug it.
Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Tallion22 I have no experience with Vue whatsoever, but you can open a new question with the related details and hopefully someone can help you!